Adapt variables of recommendations from yfinance using python
How do you adapt variables recommendations for consensus recs using yfinance library in python such as specified number of months, intervals and time period?
The script below for example will provide 4 months, 1 month interval from current date.
import pandas as pd  # Import the missing "pd" module
import yfinance as yf

# Define the stock ticker
stock = yf.Ticker("AAPL")

# Get stock info
info = stock.info

# Access analyst recommendations if available
recommendations = stock.recommendations

print(recommendations)  # Print the full DataFrame

Output
  period  strongBuy  buy  hold  sell  strongSell
0     0m         11   21     6     0           0
1    -1m         10   17    12     2           0
2    -2m         10   17    12     2           0
3    -3m         10   24     7     1           0

But trying to have script where I can specify either dates, months or intervals and then will have more periods provided
For example, periods=12, interval = 2 months, end=mm/dd/yyyy will provide 12 periods dating back a total of 24 months.
My attempt ran into a series of errors
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_analyst_recommendations(stock_ticker, num_months, interval_months, end_date=None):
    if end_date is None:
        end_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else:
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    start_date = (datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d") - timedelta(days=num_months*30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    stock = yf.Ticker(stock_ticker)
    
    if hasattr(stock, 'recommendations'):
        recommendations = stock.recommendations
        if recommendations is None or recommendations.empty:
            print(f"No analyst recommendations found for {stock_ticker}")
            return None
    else:
        print(f"Recommendations data not available for {stock_ticker}")
        return None

    recommendations = recommendations.loc[start_date:end_date]

    # Convert the index to a DatetimeIndex
    recommendations.index = pd.to_datetime(recommendations.index)

    # Resample the recommendations based on the specified interval
    resampled_recommendations = recommendations.resample(f'{interval_months}ME', label='right').agg('last')

    # Count the number of each recommendation grade
    grade_counts = resampled_recommendations.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

    # Reset the index
    grade_counts = grade_counts.reset_index()

    # Convert the relevant column to datetime and format it as a string
    grade_counts['your_datetime_column'] = pd.to_datetime(grade_counts['your_datetime_column']).dt.strftime('-%mME')

    # Set the formatted column as the index
    grade_counts = grade_counts.set_index('your_datetime_column')

    grade_counts.index = grade_counts.index.strftime('-%mME')

    # Rename the columns to match the desired output format
    grade_counts.columns = grade_counts.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
    grade_counts = grade_counts.reindex(columns=['strongBuy', 'Buy', 'Hold', 'Sell', 'strongSell']).fillna(0).astype(int)

    # Add the '0m' row at the beginning
    grade_counts.loc['0m'] = 0
    grade_counts = grade_counts.sort_index(ascending=False)

    return grade_counts

# Example usage
stock_ticker = "AAPL"
num_months = 24
interval_months = 2
end_date = "05/06/2024"

recommendations = get_analyst_recommendations(stock_ticker, num_months, interval_months, end_date)
print(recommendations)

Example of 6 periods
Custom Time-based Analyst Recommendations:
           period  strongBuy  buy  hold  sell  strongSell


 Date
2023-06-31    -9m         10   24     7     1           0
2023-08-30    -7m         10   17    12     2           0
2023-09-30    -5m         11   21     6     0           0
2023-10-31    -3m         10   24     7     1           0
2023-12-31    -1m         10   17    12     2           0
2024-02-29     0m         11   21     6     0           0  


You over-complicated thigs a little. I would suggest this approach:
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_analyst_recommendations(stock_ticker, num_periods, interval_months, end_date=None):
    if end_date is None:
        end_date = datetime.now()
    else:
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%m/%d/%Y")

    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=interval_months * 30 * num_periods)

    stock = yf.Ticker(stock_ticker)
    recommendations = stock.recommendations

    current_date = end_date
    recommendations['Date'] = [current_date - pd.DateOffset(months=i) for i in range(len(recommendations))]
    recommendations.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    recommendations = recommendations[(recommendations.index >= start_date) & (recommendations.index <= end_date)]
    if recommendations.empty:
        print("No data in the specified date range:", start_date, "to", end_date)
        return None

    resampled_recommendations = recommendations.resample(f'{interval_months}M').last()

    return resampled_recommendations

stock = yf.Ticker("AAPL")

recommendations = stock.recommendations
print("Current Analyst Recommendations:")
print(recommendations)

custom_recommendations = get_analyst_recommendations('AAPL', num_periods=12, interval_months=2, end_date='05/07/2024')
print("Custom Time-based Analyst Recommendations:")
print(custom_recommendations)

which will give you (in combination with the ordinary recomendation)
Current Analyst Recommendations:
  period  strongBuy  buy  hold  sell  strongSell
0     0m         11   21     6     0           0
1    -1m         10   17    12     2           0
2    -2m         10   17    12     2           0
3    -3m         10   24     7     1           0
Custom Time-based Analyst Recommendations:
           period  strongBuy  buy  hold  sell  strongSell
Date                                                     
2024-02-29    -3m         10   24     7     1           0
2024-04-30    -1m         10   17    12     2           0
2024-06-30     0m         11   21     6     0           0


Would still require creating new variable for each custom Time based period. Where each period is a line of output led by date (no header). See edited example. If yfinance can only output 3 at a time, can workaround by automating the variable creation, concatenating, sorting with unique dates, otherwise, wondering if this can be done when pulling from yahoo api more than the 3 dates
